# Compare secure headers from a site with ones of a list via curl inside bash script

Tags: bash, curl, http-headers, decode

when I receive value of bash script curl and compare with value of a list, the same value script not defines as the same, may when I receive data shoud I decode this value?

```
#!/bin/bash
declare  LIST_HEADERS
declare  CURL_HEADERS

RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
#list of headers from file "cfg/headersList.cfg"
while IFS=':' read -r value; do
  value="${value//\"}"
  value=${value,,}
  LIST_HEADERS+=("$value")
done < ${CONFIG[cfg]}/headersList.cfg
```

1. I receive data from file
2. recieve date from a site

```
    #list of headers from the site
while IFS=':' read value; do
   #to lower case
    value=${value,,}
    CURL_HEADERS+=("$value")
#done < <(curl -sIk ${CONFIG[baseURL]})
done < <(curl -sIk 'https://google.com')
```

3. compare these two arrays, if elements of first array match the second one its ok, if some elements is absent or not match from first this set to resulr array:

```
ArrayResult=()
for i in "${LIST_HEADERS[@]}"; do
   skip=
   for j in "${CURL_HEADERS[@]}"; do
       [[ $i == $j ]] && { skip=1; break; }
   done
   [[ -n $skip ]] || ArrayResult+=("$i")
done

if [[ -n ArrayResult[@] ]]; then
 echo -e "${RED}Array is not empty:${NC}"
 echo  "count: "${#ArrayResult[@]}
 for i in ${!ArrayResult[*]}; do
   echo "${ArrayResult[i]}"
 done
else
 echo -e "${GREEN}Array is not empty:${NC}"
 echo "Array empty"
fi
```

Comment: If you're trying to parse a JSON, use `jq`.

Comment: no, I recieve secure headers

Comment: Cate to show an example output from curl?

Comment: I added screen beneath the description

Comment: Well looks like there are more factors involved here. You might want to share the whole script that causes the issue and give enough details so we can know how to reproduce the problem ourselves.

Comment: Referrer-Policy: "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
Strict-Transport-Security: "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
X-Content-Type-Options: "nosniff"
X-Frame-Options: "SAMEORIGIN"
X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block"
Content-Security-Policy: "upgrade-insecure-requests; block-all-mixed-content"
abc: "zzz"
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN

Comment: the reason is line breaks of file